# Windows 10 Start Menu on Domain Computers

Tags: windows-10, domain, start-menu

I've looked at a lot of links and people's ideas but not sure what to do.  We have 3 clients starting to roll Windows 10 computers in a domain environments.  Two out of three have lost functionality of Start and Search and all Modern Apps.

- Logged into computer with user, no start menu functionality, no
  Cortana.  CTL-ALT-DEL opens menu and I chose switch user.
- Logged in as Domain admin
- NO start menu functionality.
- Created new Organizational Unit in Active Directory and moved
  computer to this OU.  Blocked inheritance to this OU.
- Reviewed domain policy.  It was slightly modified.  I created two
  policies, one for drive maps, and one for Shortcuts.
- Verified no Folder Redirection exists.
- Applied “Drive Maps” and “Shortcuts” Group Policies explicitly to the
  Win10+ OU.
- Executed dcGPOfix on domain controller to restore default domain and 
  default domain controller policy to default
- Reviewed local security policy to see if there are any custom
  entries.  Cleaned up some.
- Restarted endpoint.

Same issue.

- Removed computer from domain, local login as administrator - ***Works as expected***
- Removed old account profiles.  Joined computer to domain and placed
  it into new OU with inheritance blocked.  Restarted computer and
  logged in as domain administrator.

No Start Menu, Same issue.

Reviewed [online posts](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+10+start+menu+domain&oq=windows+10+start+menu+domain&aqs=chrome..69i57.4880j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and was unable to find anything that helped.

Went through all links on the first 4 pages...

- Tried to look at Registry permissions but the specific entries
  described are not in the registry on this computer.
- Looked for custom registry key where Dell has a script that runs to
  delete a key/restart to work around this issue.  Key does not exist
  on this computer.
- Verified no AD auditing was enabled
- Ensured Windows Firewall is enabled
- Modified the default domain policy, adding the computer account to
  it, in addition to authenticated users.
- Re-applied GP, restarted

Same issue.

Don't see any access denied errors in Process Monitor.

Would be nice to know what to filter for.

Executed powershell script `(Get-AppXPackage | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"} )` and restarted.
Same issue.

Copied the file `‘C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Packages\windows.immersivecontrolpanel_cw5n1h2txyewy’` to `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Packages\windows.immersivecontrolpanel_cw5n1h2txyewy’`.  Restarted
Same Issue.

- Started Application Identity service.

Same Issue

Searched AppLockers and found nothing there that could be causing this.

Located a [tool from Microsoft](http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/2/2/F22D5FDB-59CD-4275-8C95-1BE17BF70B21/startmenu.diagcab) to repair the start menu issue, downloaded and executed...
This tool failed to complete after more than 14 hours!

Login as local user while computer is domain joined and all is well.  Login back in as domain user and problem remains.

Looking for any good ideas.  We've engaged Microsoft support but they haven't been helpful yet.  I think they are using Bing to lookup what others have tried.  I tested more in 4 hours than they did in 12 on 4 phone calls.

Comment: Someone suggested, when migrating from W7 to W10, they've had issues of users having a low memory error and no start menu functionality.  This is not our situation.

He also has stayed at 1709 build of Windows 10.  That might be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

While your problem could be in **%LocalAppData%\TileDataLayer**
You could delete the contents, and reboot, but that only sometime helps.

In fact, most of the time its actually here:

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AppRepository

in this file:StateRepository-Machine.srd

This is a SQLite database which I usually open with **SQLiteDatabaseBrowserPortable**

You maybe have to completely reboot or goto into safe mode to unlock the database files.

```
reg Query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList" /s /v Sid
reg Query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList" /s /v ProfileImagePath
```

in the SQL browser:

select * from user where hex(usersid)=upper( from above);

You need to get there *id*

You then need the packages table

you need to delete all packages with that user id.

```
select * from packageuser where user=<user id>
```

review the list

```
delete from packageuser where user=<user id>
```

close and save if prompted

reboot
and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response cybernard.  The issue we see is when we log in as a new domain user that has never logged on to the computer before, the very same thing happens.  If the solution you proposed works, we would have to do this for every user (random students) that log on to each computer.  I'll look into it though.

Comment: If it is broken after you try my fix for the next user, which it shouldn't be broken any more. Then repeat the procedure for the sid connected to this profile **C:\Users\defaultuser0**.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.

Previous IT had created a GPO that executed a logon.bat that executed regedit.  Removing this and re-creating user profiles resolved the issue and Windows 10 functions normally now.  The reg file contained the following:

```
    Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders]
"AppData"=hex(2):25,00,55,00,53,00,45,00,52,00,50,00,52,00,4f,00,46,00,49,00,\
  4c,00,45,00,25,00,5c,00,41,00,70,00,70,00,6c,00,69,00,63,00,61,00,74,00,69,\
  00,6f,00,6e,00,20,00,44,00,61,00,74,00,61,00,00,00
"Desktop"=hex(2):25,00,55,00,53,00,45,00,52,00,50,00,52,00,4f,00,46,00,49,00,\
  4c,00,45,00,25,00,5c,00,44,00,65,00,73,00,6b,00,74,00,6f,00,70,00,00,00
"Favorites"=hex(2):25,00,55,00,53,00,45,00,52,00,50,00,52,00,4f,00,46,00,49,00,\
  4c,00,45,00,25,00,5c,00,46,00,61,00,76,00,6f,00,72,00,69,00,74,00,65,00,73,\
  00,00,00
"NetHood"=hex(2):25,00,55,00,53,00,45,00,52,00,50,00,52,00,4f,00,46,00,49,00,\
  4c,00,45,00,25,00,5c,00,4e,00,65,00,74,00,48,00,6f,00,6f,00,64,00,00,00
"Personal"=hex(2):5c,00,5c,00,50,00,41,00,4e,00,54,00,48,00,45,00,52,00,2d,00,\
  46,00,49,00,4c,00,45,00,5c,00,53,00,74,00,75,00,64,00,65,00,6e,00,74,00,5c,\
  00,25,00,75,00,73,00,65,00,72,00,6e,00,61,00,6d,00,65,00,25,00,00,00
"PrintHood"=hex(2):25,00,55,00,53,00,45,00,52,00,50,00,52,00,4f,00,46,00,49,00,\
  4c,00,45,00,25,00,5c,00,50,00,72,00,69,00,6e,00,74,00,48,00,6f,00,6f,00,64,\
  00,00,00
"Programs"=hex(2):25,00,55,00,53,00,45,00,52,00,50,00,52,00,4f,00,46,00,49,00,\
  4c,00,45,00,25,00,5c,00,53,00,74,00,61,00,72,00,74,00,20,00,4d,00,65,00,6e,\
  00,75,00,5c,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,73,00,00,00
"Recent"=hex(2):25,00,55,00,53,00,45,00,52,00,50,00,52,00,4f,00,46,00,49,00,4c,\
  00,45,00,25,00,5c,00,52,00,65,00,63,00,65,00,6e,00,74,00,00,00
"SendTo"=hex(2):25,00,55,00,53,00,45,00,52,00,50,00,52,00,4f,00,46,00,49,00,4c,\
  00,45,00,25,00,5c,00,53,00,65,00,6e,00,64,00,54,00,6f,00,00,00
"Start Menu"=hex(2):25,00,55,00,53,00,45,00,52,00,50,00,52,00,4f,00,46,00,49,\
  00,4c,00,45,00,25,00,5c,00,53,00,74,00,61,00,72,00,74,00,20,00,4d,00,65,00,\
  6e,00,75,00,00,00
"Startup"=hex(2):25,00,55,00,53,00,45,00,52,00,50,00,52,00,4f,00,46,00,49,00,\
  4c,00,45,00,25,00,5c,00,53,00,74,00,61,00,72,00,74,00,20,00,4d,00,65,00,6e,\
  00,75,00,5c,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,73,00,5c,00,53,00,\
  74,00,61,00,72,00,74,00,75,00,70,00,00,00
"Templates"=hex(2):25,00,55,00,53,00,45,00,52,00,50,00,52,00,4f,00,46,00,49,00,\
  4c,00,45,00,25,00,5c,00,54,00,65,00,6d,00,70,00,6c,00,61,00,74,00,65,00,73,\
  00,00,00
"Cookies"=hex(2):25,00,55,00,53,00,45,00,52,00,50,00,52,00,4f,00,46,00,49,00,\
  4c,00,45,00,25,00,5c,00,43,00,6f,00,6f,00,6b,00,69,00,65,00,73,00,00,00
"My Pictures"=hex(2):5c,00,5c,00,50,00,41,00,4e,00,54,00,48,00,45,00,52,00,2d,\
  00,46,00,49,00,4c,00,45,00,5c,00,53,00,74,00,75,00,64,00,65,00,6e,00,74,00,\
  5c,00,25,00,75,00,73,00,65,00,72,00,6e,00,61,00,6d,00,65,00,25,00,5c,00,4d,\
  00,79,00,20,00,50,00,69,00,63,00,74,00,75,00,72,00,65,00,73,00,00,00
"Local Settings"=hex(2):25,00,55,00,53,00,45,00,52,00,50,00,52,00,4f,00,46,00,\
  49,00,4c,00,45,00,25,00,5c,00,4c,00,6f,00,63,00,61,00,6c,00,20,00,53,00,65,\
  00,74,00,74,00,69,00,6e,00,67,00,73,00,00,00
"Local AppData"=hex(2):25,00,55,00,53,00,45,00,52,00,50,00,52,00,4f,00,46,00,\
  49,00,4c,00,45,00,25,00,5c,00,4c,00,6f,00,63,00,61,00,6c,00,20,00,53,00,65,\
  00,74,00,74,00,69,00,6e,00,67,00,73,00,5c,00,41,00,70,00,70,00,6c,00,69,00,\
  63,00,61,00,74,00,69,00,6f,00,6e,00,20,00,44,00,61,00,74,00,61,00,00,00
"Cache"=hex(2):25,00,55,00,53,00,45,00,52,00,50,00,52,00,4f,00,46,00,49,00,4c,\
  00,45,00,25,00,5c,00,4c,00,6f,00,63,00,61,00,6c,00,20,00,53,00,65,00,74,00,\
  74,00,69,00,6e,00,67,00,73,00,5c,00,54,00,65,00,6d,00,70,00,6f,00,72,00,61,\
  00,72,00,79,00,20,00,49,00,6e,00,74,00,65,00,72,00,6e,00,65,00,74,00,20,00,\
  46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,00,00
"History"=hex(2):25,00,55,00,53,00,45,00,52,00,50,00,52,00,4f,00,46,00,49,00,\
  4c,00,45,00,25,00,5c,00,4c,00,6f,00,63,00,61,00,6c,00,20,00,53,00,65,00,74,\
  00,74,00,69,00,6e,00,67,00,73,00,5c,00,48,00,69,00,73,00,74,00,6f,00,72,00,\
  79,00,00,00
```